# Is it possible to use the same graph for two activities with Navigation Jetpack?

Tags: android-activity, graph, android-jetpack, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack-navigation

I want to migrate my app in order to use a Navigation Jetpack component.
I have a bottom navigation with 4 items.
Each item is an activity.
Could I use the same graph to share it between these activities?

Comment: use fragments instead